# how to show touches via ADB in android?

Tags: android, adb

I want to perform touch event via ADB and at the same time how can i show that touch in android using show touch option present in developer options.

I tried with command

```
adb shell input tap 100 100
```

by enabling show touches options but i won't be able to see touch icon, is there any way to do this both task sending touch event and showing it via show touch options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this by sending event using sendevent command and enabling show touches option in android we can achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't have a very old android device

**Go to Setting -> 
Developer options (enable it if not avaibale) -> 
(scroll down) Check/Enable the "Pointer Location"**

After this you will see small colored dots on the location touched

Comment: Thank you for the response but that is not what i am looking for because pointer location also displays x and y co ordinates i simply want to display touch icon.